# How can I create launcher icon for PhpStorm?

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher

I have PhpStorm on my PC, to launch it I have to go to phpstorm/bin/ and launch phpstorm.sh, how can I pin this to launcher so that I dont have to go into folders every time?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Use IDE to create launcher. Open **Tools -> Create Desktop Entry...**

**Alternate method**:

You need to create a application launcher first.

Installing gnome-panel

```
 sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel
```

To create launcher

```
sudo gnome-desktop-item-edit /usr/share/applications/ --create-new
```

This will open up a "Create Launcher" window

> **Type**: Application
>   **Name**: PhpStorm
>   **Command**: /bin/bash path_to/phpstorm.sh
>   **Comment**: Any Comment

This will create a launcher file in `/usr/share/applications` directory. Now double click and open the file.

Once the file is launched. You can see the process in the unity launcher. Right click on the icon in the unity launcher and click "**Lock to Launcher**"

Alternatively you can create a .desktop file

Found this .desktop file [**here**](http://aaronbonner.tumblr.com/post/22580253608/phpstorm-and-ubuntu-unity). I haven't tested it. Try your luck.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=JetBrains PhpStorm
Exec=/opt/PhpStorm/bin/phpstorm.sh %f
Icon=/opt/PhpStorm/bin/webide.png
Comment=Develop with pleasure!
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-phpstorm
```

Comment: This right here is one of the reasons Linux has such a limited user base.

Comment: @Webnet This right here is an example of someone who has the wrong information. See the other answer.

Comment: Great!Great!Great!

Comment: This is no longer necessary as PhpStorm can now be installed as a snap, which does this for you.  See my answer here for details.

Answer (score 179):

Run `Tools` —> `Create Desktop Entry` in top menu of IDE.

Comment: Seems not to work in 13.04 :(

Comment: Works for me in 13.04!

Comment: Works for WebStorm EAP 11 and Ubuntu 14 as well.

Comment: Why does Jetbrains not include this (by default, mind you) in their bash script installation?

Comment: Where is checkbox Create Desktop Entry in installation wizard.

Comment: @MikeMurko what installation script? The one inside bin is executable, not installable.

Comment: @JorgeeFG if you check their latest download instructions: "Run PhpStorm.sh from the bin subdirectory"

Comment: works for me in 16.04 and PhpStorm 2016.2

Comment: Still working, 16.04, PhpStorm 2017.3. Thanks!

Comment: Works for me with KDE Kubuntu.

Comment: This is no longer necessary as PhpStorm can now be installed as a snap, which does this for you.  See my answer here for details.

Comment: still works (ubuntu 20, phpstorm 2020.2)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 20):

Try changing the two below lines in the file
`~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-phpstorm.desktop`

```
Icon=/home/$USER/Downloads/PhpStorm-138.2000.2262/bin/webide.png
Exec="/home/$USER/Downloads/PhpStorm-138.2000.2262/bin/phpstorm.sh" %f
```

Comment: This worked to change the existing launcher icon to now launch 8 instead of 7.

Comment: I noticed the same desktop file is also placed in /usr/share/applications (I probably installed for all users on the system). You might have to edit this file as well!

Comment: On KDE this answer worked for me. I've installed phpstorm using snap and the icon extension in this path was `svg`. I created a new `png` icon and follow your instructions. Now it shows properly. Thanks

Comment: works on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 19):

Go to `Tools-> "Create Desktop Entry"`

[image: Phpstorm 8 Tools menu]

Comment: May be need restart session if entry not appeared after creation.

Comment: The exact same answer has been given 2,5 years ago: https://askubuntu.com/a/223833/297583.

Comment: This works for me... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

By far the easiest solution is to open PhpStorm, where it will show in the launcher.  Then right click on it in the launcher and select "Lock to Launcher" and your done.

Comment: When you do this in KDE plasms, you can obtain an Icon that launch anything but the java virtual machine

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to do anything.
Just run PhpStorm/PyCharm for the first time from a command line with

> /path/PhpStorm/bin/phpstorm.sh

And after it will start a popup will appear asking you for a password to add it to a launcher. When you will submit your password an ico will appear in the launcher.

Answer (score 2):

From terminal, `cd` into `{installation home}/bin` and type: `./webstorm.sh`

This will open the app and from the IDE go to **Tools** —> **Create Desktop Entry** in the top menu and then close the app. Now, you can open it from the system menu.

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On KDE Plasma 5.17.14,
I had to create a new Item in the menu.

Right-click on the application launchermenu, clickEdit Applications...to start KMenuEdit.

In the Development group, right-click and "add a new item", enter PHPStorm for example. Then Ok.

With this item selected, on the right part on the window, update the "command" field with "path/to/phpstormFolder/bin/phpstorm.sh"

Click on the icon on right in order to set the application icon: 
Other Icon, browse and put : "path/to/phpstormFolder/bin/phpstorm.png"

File/save. If you find any issue with writing the .menu file, check the permissions of /home/"your_user"/.config/menus

It's done, you can access the launcher in the usual Appliocations launcher.

If you want to get it the task bar, in the application launcher, on the PHPStorm entry, richt click and "pin to task Manager"

Answer (score 1):

*Late in the party but this might be useful*

**Step-1**:    `cd /usr/share/applications/`

**Step-2**: Create a file `sudo touch jetbrains-phpstorm.desktop`

**Step-3**: Then `sudo vi jetbrains-phpstorm.desktop`

**Step-4**: open new terminal goto folder phpstrom bin folder and enter `pwd`
for example in my case: `cd ~/Downloads/PhpStorm-213.5744.279/bin && pwd`

**Step-5**: then in vi copy-paste this

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=PhpStorm
Icon=<pwd copied path of bin>/phpstorm.png
Exec="<pwd copied path of bin>/phpstorm.sh" %f
Comment=Develop with pleasure!
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-phpstorm
```

**Note:** change `<pwd copied path of bin>` with the copied path of phpstorm bin in Step-4

to save press the <kbd>ESC</kbd> button followed by `:wq`

any mistake then press the <kbd>ESC</kbd> button followed by `:q!`

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

As of 2017-12-14, you can install PhpStorm as a snap, either from the Ubuntu Software application, or the command line.  See [Install PhpStorm with Snaps](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/12/install-phpstorm-with-snaps/) for details.

This will automatically add a launcher icon to your desktop.

Comment: Snap's install brought a `svn` icon which seems doesn't render properly on KDE. I followed @Young answer with a created `png` icon and worked