# PHPStorm favorite not working after changing version

Tags: 20.04

I installed PHPStorm as a standalone software (meaning I just downloaded it and started the program via terminal in bin folder).

While it was open I clicked on the sidebar (rightclick->save to favorites) so I can start it from there (this was working).

Then I realized that it was the wrong version, I wanted to download the EAP version. So I deinstalled it, simply by removing the JetBeans config directory as explained [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/uninstall.html#standalone). Then I downloaded the EAP version, removed the old favicon and created a new one.

The problem is, the new favicon still starts the old application. Now I removed also the downloaded folder of the old PHPStorm application. Now nothing happens when I click on the favicon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Run `Tools` —> `Create Desktop Entry` in top menu of IDE as suggested here https://askubuntu.com/a/223833/247771

However, this was not creating a new favorite or desktop icon. I also tried to reboot, but that didn't help.

However, when I now save the current favicon on the sidebar while the new program is open, it points to right EAP program.